# Why pip install fails unless I pin a version?

Tags: python, pip

I have a package in my pypi repo in which the version has a prefix like `package_foo:bar-0.1.0`.

I can install this package for example with `pip install package_foo>=bar-0`, `pip install package_foo==bar-0.1.0`, `pip install package_foo>=bar-0,<bar-1`...  however, running a simple `pip install package_foo` fails with:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package_foo (from versions: bar-0.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for package_foo
```

What's the most likely reason for this? Notice this is the unusual issue. Usually the problem is that one has problems pinning a version, which is not my case. Also notice that `pip` is actually detecting the version `(from versions: bar-0.1.0)`, so why it's not installing it?

UPDATE

output of `pip install -vv package_foo`

```
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/mv/0frvv9jj44d68kzfvgw72wvc0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-2gg4a0q5
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/mv/0frvv9jj44d68kzfvgw72wvc0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-p4ppfxwu
Created requirements tracker '/private/var/folders/mv/0frvv9jj44d68kzfvgw72wvc0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-p4ppfxwu'
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/mv/0frvv9jj44d68kzfvgw72wvc0000gn/T/pip-install-1atqi_8x
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.example.com/repository/pypi-all/simple
1 location(s) to search for versions of package-foo:
* https://pypi.example.com/repository/pypi-all/simple/package-foo/
Getting page https://pypi.example.com/repository/pypi-all/simple/package-foo/
Found credentials in url for pypi.example.com
Looking up "https://pypi.example.com/repository/pypi-all/simple/package-foo/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.example.com:443
https://pypi.example.com:443 "GET /repository/pypi-all/simple/package-foo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Updating cache with response from "https://pypi.example.com/repository/pypi-all/simple/package-foo/"
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.example.com/repository/pypi-all/simple/package-foo/
  Found link https://pypi.example.com/repository/pypi-all/packages/package-foo/bar-0.1.0/package_foo-bar-0.1.0.tar.gz#md5=ce310afa2f5ade4af3b216fd1ece0498 (from https://pypi.example.com/repository/pypi-all/simple/package-foo/), version: bar-0.1.0
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'package-foo': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package_foo (from versions: bar-0.1.0)
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker '/private/var/folders/mv/0frvv9jj44d68kzfvgw72wvc0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-p4ppfxwu'
ERROR: No matching distribution found for package_foo
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yzT/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/yzT/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 382, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/Users/yzT/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 201, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/Users/yzT/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 365, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Users/yzT/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 311, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req.populate_link(self.finder, upgrade_allowed, self.require_hashes)
  File "/Users/yzT/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 225, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/Users/yzT/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 906, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for package_foo
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `pip install -vv package_foo`. It should list all of the found versions.

Comment: @AlexisBRENON added

Comment: It seems that the package is found and version parsed correctly but pip refuses to install it... Your version number is not following the [version identifier](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) scheme. Did you try to use a more "classical" version number/name (0.1.0+bar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version name/number is not [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) compliant. Hence `pip` consider it as a [pre-release](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#pre-release-versions) version and does not install it "by default".

Adding a Requirement specifier (as `==bar-0.1.0`) or using the `--pre` option (`pip install --pre package_foo`) should fix your problem.

I would recommend to change your versionning scheme to make it PEP440 and/or [SemVer](https://semver.org/) compliant.

Comment: in my case, I uploaded the package to my pypi repo as  `0.1.0+bar` and it's fine  now